# Ultra-lightweight material for structural components - aluminium foam?

Tags: materials, construction, outgassing

This is (again) something from the back of my head, that I am looking for right now. I think that in 2008, I saw a presentation on **foamed / expanded aluminium** for structural components (1). The promise was to enable roughly 10 times lighter structures in aluminium as compared to a structure with an equivalent strength made from *solid* aluminium. It was at an ESA meeting, so it should come from either somewhere in Europe or Canada. I can not find it and actually I do not know how it is called. *Foam* does not seem to be the term. It was about *really small bubbles* of some sort, similar to or smaller than in foam plastic. I do not know about outgassing in this context, maybe the *bubbles* were evacuated. It would be interesting to find out more. There are some composites / polymers in use in space, for which foam has at least been investigated, but this is sort of not what I am looking for.

*(1) EDIT: I need to specify this. I am talking about structural components of space crafts or satellites. Think of structures in terms of skeletons. Launchers are interesting, but not the scope of this question. It also means, that I prefer a source, which talks about the use in space (longer duration, weeks, months, years), space applications (proposals for or documentation of structural component xyz of mission abc) or space qualification of the material (an analysis of its mechanical properties plus [thermal] vacuum tests is probably most interesting in this case).*

Answer (score 10):

**Usage as blast containers**

I found a [short article by NASA](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110023870_2011025092.pdf) investigating the use of aluminium foam. Whilst they don't intend to use it for the majority of the space craft design they do intend to use it to replace their blast containers.

NASA were looking for a replacement for their blast containers, the job of which is:

> The blast containers are
>   used to safely trap the debris
>   from small explosions that
>   are initiated at liftoff to sever
>   frangible nuts on hold-down
>   studs that secure the spacecraft to a mobile launch platform until liftoff

The results of their testing with aluminum foam were as below.

> On the basis of
>   the results of these tests, aluminum foam
>   liners with densities of 16 and 24 percent
>   were selected. Sample foam liners were
>   tested in a simulated launch configuration (see figure). The results of the tests
>   showed that suitably designed and fabricated aluminum foam liners absorb energy more effectively than the solid lead
>   liners do.

**Uses as Shielding**

Aside from blast containers we also have their plans for it to be used as [shielding from micro meteoroids and debris.](http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/trs/_techrep/TM-2009-214793.pdf)

This paper compares existing honeycomb structures to that of the foam

> The purpose of this study was to evaluate the effect on shielding performance achieved by replacing 
>   metallic honeycomb cores with metallic open-cell foam cores in a double-sandwich panel MMOD 
>   shielding configuration representative of those used onboard the ISS.

And the conclusion of the experiment was that:

> At normal incidence, the foam-modified shield was found to provide a 15% improvement in critical 
>   projectile diameter at low velocity (3 km/s) and a 3% increase at high velocity (7 km/s)

The technical details below this point explain mostly why they intend to use it, its strength to weight ratio and ability to contain blasts being the main one.

**Properties of the foam**

Aluminium Foam does seem to be the correct name for what you are thinking of.

Aluminium Foam is produced from an aluminium alloy.

The [mechanical properties](http://www.goodfellow.com/catalogue/GFCat4J.php?ewd_token=dYepC9mINoxB1BQgLQabdwzFe4xwaZ&n=W7S8wAkxXaN7tKH5Q61NDDNp3c4fyz) of this foam are:

- High Surface area to unit volume
- High strength to weight ratio
- Completely Isotropic load response

The foam also takes on a lot of the properties of the alloy it is made from, namely:

- Corrosion Resistance
- Electrical Conductivity
- Thermal Conductivity

The aluminium foam itself has a bubbly appearance much like [This Image of the aluminium foam](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aClosed_cell_aluminium_foam_with_small_cell_size.JPG)

**Further Reading**

Further reading can be found in [this](http://www.metalfoam.net/papers/simancik1997b.pdf) paper on its potential uses structurally.

Comment: This may actually be the *alloy*, I do not know. Thanks anyway. But it does not help me in terms of finding the right term for *foam* in this context ...

Comment: @ernestopheles i just edited this, please take a look at my last line, i think i even found the paper you were referring to

Comment: Yep, so I saw. This is actually very good. I am still missing a connection to space applications, but this is close :-)

Comment: @ernestopheles bam, summary of its potential uses for space. Any closer?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I have gone through the paper myself. *Speculating like you*, yes, this is useful stuff. *But* the space people have a few trades, one of them is to investigate space-worthiness of every material before it is used in space. Stuff like [thermal] vacuum tests, for instance. There are catalogues of criteria, which need to be matched. **Then** and only then people talk about space applications in literature, performance on key criteria included. Not before. It actually means that this needs another source ...

Comment: other sources, ok what kinds are you specifically searching for? Others that agree on its use in space or others agreeing on its uses as we speculated?

Comment: For a start, a source which explicitly mentions terms like "space application" and "[space] qualified" or similar. It's a bit hard, I know, I have not found it myself yet ...

Comment: @ernestopheles ok you got it, give me some time, ill hunt them down if they exist. Youve piqued my interest now i **Have** to know

Comment: @ernestopheles ok, how about an article and tests by NASA, took a bit of hunting but shows its applications and their initial intentions for it!

Comment: Cool, again thanks for the efforts, I did not know about *this* stuff. It goes a bit into the same direction as what Rory mentioned in his answer. The foam is used to stop (and collect) objects (projectiles / dust). It is not really useful in my context, because it is not a structural component (think of a skeleton). And it is used on a launcher (rocket), which needs to survive under space conditions for a rather short time (minutes max). For the latter, I should adjust my question and clarify this, I am interested in satellites etc. Anyway, I appreciate your enthusiasm :-)

Comment: @ernestopheles are you sure such a thing exists? I searched for over 2 hours finding nothing related to it, are you sure it progressed beyond the presentation into practical tests? If youre sure it had practical tests then i will take another stab at it, im just as interested as you are by this point

Comment: It should, it was presented, there was some research on it - I remember it clearly, I was dealing with some overweight equipment at that time, though we went for another solution. Maybe they did not went into production or maybe it was never launched into space on some mission. Maybe they never managed to fully qualify it for space flight after all. Maybe it became a product and got a strange name for marketing reasons. Maybe there is another technical term than foam because of some chemical reason or .... whatever. No idea. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is Aerogel - Www.aerogel.org. There are a few different kinds, some of which are flexible and light, at above 99.9% air, and others that are more rigid, with a lower air content.

The solid used can vary too, from graphite to aluminium or silica, depending on the required properties.

The silica aerogels are incredibly good at blocking heat transfer, as you can see in this pic from http://stardust.jpl.nasa.gov/tech/aerogel.html

[image]

Comment: This is kind of a good direction, although not completely what I am looking for. This stuff is not used for major structural parts as far as I know. It is also much lighter than what I remember - the stuff which was explicitly proposed for structures.

Comment: I'll hunt for the variant then, I think it was still over 90% air, that was more rigid.

Comment: Was this it @ernestopheles - http://www.aerogel.org/?p=1058

Comment: Nice page, need to read it in details. But still does not match it. Looks like rather flexible stuff - something you just do not want in structures (which e.g. need to survive lift-of).

Answer (score 4):

There is a commonly used Aluminum Honeycomb design. The idea is, instead of using solid aluminum, sandwich an aluminum honeycomb design between two aluminum plates. This works well for structural purposes, provides a bit of flexibility, and reduces the weight. That might be what you are referring to. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_structure) that shows some common designs, including [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CompositeSandwich.png):

[image]

Comment: I know honeycomb, but this definitely not what I am looking for.